# OnActivityResults in fragment not called

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult

**UPDATE**:
I have restarted my device, and it works now. Like a magic!!

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
I have read many answers for my question, but i still can't get a solution for my problem:
I had 1 fragment that opened an intent for capturing a photo and in the fragment I had the method OnActivityResults and all worked fine.
Now, I added 2nd fragment that also calls an intent with the same code (but different request code). I'm not sure that this cause the problem, but now, when I push the "V" that approve the captured photo, I'm getting back to different fragment and the OnActivityResults method isn't called.

In the fragment:

```
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 11;
private static final int REQUEST_ATTACH_PHOTO_CODE = 22;

    takePhotoButton = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonTakePhoto);

            takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(MainActivity.deviceHasCamera){
                        Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(photoIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_CODE );
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "No camera detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });



  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("EB", "onActivityResult CarAccident");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
                //This case is when the user decide to Approve the captured photo
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    Log.d("EB", "BitMap = " + photo.toString());
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ATTACH_PHOTO_CODE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    Log.d("EB", "Uri fata.getData() = " + data.getData().toString());
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = this.activity.getContentResolver().query(
                            selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    //For the case that is Android 5.0 and the photo is on the server
                    // and not on the device
                    if (photo == null){
                        try {
                            photo = getBitmapFromUri(data.getData());
                            Log.d("EB", "photo = getBitmapFromUri(data.getData()) = " + photo.toString());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(this.activity, FAILD_TO_ATTACH_PHOTO_MESSAGE,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    //Set the photo to the imageView
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                   Log.d("EB", "attached image = " + ((photo != null) ? photo.toString() : "NULL"));
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

I tried to to write in the host Activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

But it's not working. Hope you can help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Include the code where you are calling startActivityForResult with request code REQUEST_ATTACH_PHOTO_CODE.

Comment: I have restarted my device, and it works now. Like a magic!!

Comment: duplicate question [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29369154/1283715)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this.
You must call it in your `Activity` and check if the result true with `REQUEST_CODE`. If equeals with your code, you must retrieve your data from method and do what you need. This is origin solution.